# Bash vi mode: simulating Enter in binding

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I have a function `fh()` in my .bashrc. I want to bind Ctrl-F in vi-insert-mode to run this function.

I have tried

```
bind '"\C-F":"fh\n"'
```

This types fh into my terminal and tries to autocomplete the command. After having searched around on the web I was under the impressing that \n was supposed to simulate a press of the Enter key.

I have found plenty of threads on binding bash commands in vi-insert-mode, but none that talk about functions.

Is there perhaps a way to make a binding in .inputrc instead of .bashrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I find a solution 5 minutes after posting the question, but after hours of searching for an answer..

I replaced `\n` with the literal character for enter, which is shown as`^M` in vim.

Quote from bakunins comment in [this](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/137074-how-enter-return-key-bash-script.html) thread from unix.com

> Anyway, to enter a literal "ENTER key" open your scripts file in vi.
>
> - Position the cursor where you want to enter the  key and use "i" to go into insert mode.
> - Then enter CTRL-V, which makes vi accept the next character as literal. Press the ENTER key then, which should result in a "^M" appearing on the screen.
>
> Notice, that "^M" is not two characters (caret and "M"), but one. You will see that when you go over it with the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a script instead of a function.